# Button anchor doesn't relocate as fast as other controls in group

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to keep two buttons in the same location in the groupbox, while the other controls can be resized.

Here's what it looks like normally, without resizing. I want those two buttons to stay in the same relative spot ***inside*** the groupbox.

[image: Fresh instance without resizing.]

It works when I resize the form left or right, but when I resize it up or down,
the buttons seems to move at a rate slower than the other controls in the groupbox.

[image: Making form larger]

[image: Making form smaller]

Here's the relevant designer code:

```
// 
        // groupBox1
        // 
        this.groupBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.groupBox1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.button_delete);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.button_add);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.list_files);
        this.groupBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Console", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 42);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(502, 297);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "Audio";
        // 
        // list_files
        // 
        this.list_files.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.list_files.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.list_files.GridLines = true;
        this.list_files.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 18);
        this.list_files.Name = "list_files";
        this.list_files.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(489, 239);
        this.list_files.TabIndex = 0;
        this.list_files.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.list_files.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.List;
        // 
        // button_add
        // 
        this.button_add.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.button_add.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 264);
        this.button_add.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button_add.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button_add.Name = "button_add";
        this.button_add.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button_add.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button_add.Text = "Add File";
        this.button_add.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button_add.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_add_Click);
        // 
        // button_delete
        // 
        this.button_delete.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.button_delete.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(88, 264);
        this.button_delete.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(91, 23);
        this.button_delete.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(91, 23);
        this.button_delete.Name = "button_delete";
        this.button_delete.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(91, 23);
        this.button_delete.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button_delete.Text = "Remove File";
        this.button_delete.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button_delete.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_delete_Click);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try anchoring the buttons left and bottom.  It looks like you are anchoring them left and right.